# PHP - Default function argument to new object

Tags: php, laravel

I'm trying to create a function with an optional argument, and if the argument is not passed in then default to an empty Laravel Collection.

I've tried the following:

```
function myFunction(string $string, Collection $collection = [])
```

Result: Can't use an array as a default parameter for Collection object

```
function myFunction(string $string, Collection $collection = collect([]))
```

Result: constant expression contains invalid operations

```
function myFunction(string $string, Collection $collection = new Collection)
```

Result: constant expression contains invalid operations

What I can do is the following:

```
function myFunction(string $string, Collection $collection = null){
    $collection = $collection ?? new Collection;
}
```

Is there a better way to do this or should I stick with what I've got?

Comment: $collection = $collection ?? new Collection;

Comment: @GiacomoM Thanks I can do that, but hoping to find out whether it can be done in the arguments

Comment: In the second example, why you use collect([]) instead of collect() (you do not need of the square brackets)

Comment: @GiacomoM Didn't know that. thought it needed an array so passed in an empty one

Comment: Maybe you can try Collection $collection =  null, but I am not sure

Comment: I think you already have the best you can do (for now). I'd be tempted to add a question mark to allow nulls to be passed explicitly. Might save a fatal error down the line. `, ?Collection $collection = null)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'll post an answer as I think it's clear enough.

From [the docs](https://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.arguments.php#functions.arguments.default), section "Example #6 Using non-scalar types as default values section":

> The default value must be a constant expression, not (for example) a
> variable, a class member or a function call.

So no, you can't use an object as a default value. Your final example seems to be the best you can do.

As mentioned in the comments above, I'd recommend making the variable nullable to avoid fatal errors if someone explicitly passes a null.

```
function myFunction(string $string, ?Collection $collection = null){
    $collection = is_null($collection) ? new Collection : $collection;
}
```